# swift ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier 'authData'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I do not know why its saying that 'uid' has no member.

> Type 'User' has no member 'user'

My code:

```
@IBAction func signIn (_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error) in

                if error == nil {

                    self.userUid = authDataResult?.user.uid

                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set((User.user.uid)!, forKey: "uid")

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMessages", sender: nil)
                } else {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignUp", sender: nil)
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a class reference, that is you expect the class `User` to have a static property `user` which it doesn't

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.set((User.user.uid)!, forKey: "uid")
```

Maybe you meant the uid you just read

```
KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.userUid!, forKey: "uid")
```